# how to avoid overlapping of fragment?

Tags: overlap

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // New fragment 
            Fragment frag = new KidSectionFragment1();
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.frame, frag);
            ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);   
            ft.commit();
        }
    });
```

I am creating a fragment over another fragment. but the child fragment is getting overlapped over the parent fragment...
how do i remove the content of parent fragment..